# How to disable setInterval function and start it again

Tags: javascript, setinterval

setInterval "MoveToPlayer" should start after meeting first condition from "checkPosition" method and it should run(this works). After meeting the same condition again it should stop and start again with different parameter. I through that simple placing clearInterval(MoveToPlayer) will do the job but it doesn't work.
Second issue is how to stop this interval for example from "checkPosition" method?

```
  class player {
    constructor(name, PosY) {
      this.name = name;
      this.PosX = 5;
      this.PosY = PosY;
      this.object = $('.' + name);
      this.speed = 0;
      this.direction = "";
      this.lifes = 3;
    }

playerMove(thisRaft) {
  var MoveToPlayer = setInterval(() => {
    clearInterval(MoveToPlayer)
    $('.player1').css('left', thisRaft.PosX * 50);
    $('.player1').css('bottom', thisRaft.PosY * 50);
  }, 1);
}

checkPosition(x, y) {
  for (var i = 0; i < raftsTab.length; i++) {
    if (x == raftsTab[i].PosX && y == raftsTab[i].PosY) {
      let thisRaft = raftsTab[i];
      this.playerMove(thisRaft);
      return;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < raftsTab.length; i++) {
    if (x !== raftsTab[i].PosX && y !== raftsTab[i].PosY && y !== 0 && y !== 5 && y !== 10) {
      console.log("Dead");
      player1.PosX = 5;
      player1.PosY = 0;
      changePosition();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Move the variable declaration out of the function.

Comment: Do you really need interval of 1 **ms** ?

Comment: @barbsan It is a game and I need to be sure that to small interval is not a problem. When I will solve general problem with my game I will try to experiment with  biggre value.

Comment: Don't you think setTimeout is more appropriate then setInterval for your use case ?

Comment: Protoxy no because it is game like old frogger. Player has to jump to raft and flow on it until next move.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding your first issue you are clearing the interval immediately after it starts, so it won't continue.
2. In order to make the interval more dynamic you should have a function that returns an interval within `checkPosition`.
   Wasn't able to understand how your game should actually work, but I am posting an alteration to your script where I modified `PlayerMove` and checkPosition in away that gives you a better control of the interval in question.

Hope it is clear and helpful for you

```js
  class player {
    constructor(name, PosY) {
      this.name = name;
      this.PosX = 5;
      this.PosY = PosY;
      this.object = $('.' + name);
      this.speed = 0;
      this.direction = "";
      this.lifes = 3;
    }

playerMove(thisRaft) {
  return setInterval(() => {
    $('.player1').css('left', thisRaft.PosX * 50);
    $('.player1').css('bottom', thisRaft.PosY * 50);
  }, 1);
}

checkPosition(x, y) {
  if (someCondition && this.currentPlayerMove) {
    clearInterval(this.currentPlayerMove)
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < raftsTab.length; i++) {
    if (x == raftsTab[i].PosX && y == raftsTab[i].PosY) {
      let thisRaft = raftsTab[i];
      this.currentPlayerMove = this.playerMove(thisRaft);
      return;
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < raftsTab.length; i++) {
    if (x !== raftsTab[i].PosX && y !== raftsTab[i].PosY && y !== 0 && y !== 5 && y !== 10) {
      console.log("Dead");
      player1.PosX = 5;
      player1.PosY = 0;
      changePosition();
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks DSCH. I finally used solution from comment below but anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Just assign your handler at such scope, that would make it accessible to all functions that could clear it.

```js
var handler;

function movePlayer(text){
  clearInterval(handler); // stop execution before assigning new handler
  handler = setInterval(()=>{
    /* do your stuff */
    console.log(text);
  }, 100)
}

movePlayer("I'm moving")

setTimeout(()=>{
  clearInterval(handler)
}, 500)

setTimeout(()=>{
  movePlayer("I'm moving again")
}, 1500)

setTimeout(()=>{
  clearInterval(handler)
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Thanks barbsan. It works. Admittedly I get new issue but clearing interval finally works